# Filter questions based on answer rate

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accept-rate, filtering

I'd like to be able to filter out questions asked by users who have less than an N% accept rate and who have asked a minimum of M questions. The value of M and N would be set on a per-user basis, or on a server-wide basis.

This could be a feature available to users after achieving a certain reputation threshold.

Comment: Declined as [accept rate is no longer shown with on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Answer (score 4):

These kinds of suggestions are why that fool statistic should never have been made so prominent.

We don't do fine grained filtering here. Indeed, so far we don't do *any* user filtering at all, and that is how it should be.

I swear I'm going to stop accepting answer (not that I ask many questions).

Comment: Super upvote wishing time!

Answer (score 2):

If a huge number of high-rep users turned off the newbie noise, then no newbies would get good answers, and the site would fade away.

If you're not growing, then you're declining.

Comment: High-rep users aren't answering those 40-question, 0%-answer rate users, anyway, so that's a moot point.

Comment: @Shaggy: But they're still seeing the questions, and commenting "dude, what is up with your accept rate?" and "dude, ask a complete question!", but under your proposal this wouldn't happen.

Comment: *This* high rep user doesn't give a hoot about accept rates. If there are user I'm not answering it is because they ask questions I'm not good on or because they ask un-answerably vague and poorly worded questions.

Comment: That's fine, but you stated a premise about *other* high-rep users which just doesn't hold.

Comment: @Shaggy, I think your overestimating the amount of high-rep users who aren't answering those questions.  Of course it depends on where you measure high rep.  If the accept rate is in the data dump, you could probably determine an exact percentage.

Comment: @Ether In my experience, the users who have such pitiful accept rates aren't worth my time since they clearly don't care about the quid pro quo nature of the site. I'd rather spend my time answering questions for people who are willing to spend that extra three seconds accepting an answer, and from the looks of it, I'd say that's the dominant attitude of SO users.

Comment: @Lance Roberts I could certainly be overestimating, but after using the site for half a year, that's the pattern I've observed, and I'd be willing to put money down on it.

Comment: @Shaggy, good answers generate more points in votes than acceptances. Sometimes a *lot* more. Even if you are hung up on rep, acceptances just don't factor in at a sky high level. Some users *do* ask crap questions that will never generate a lot of rep, but that is a feature of the questions, not of the lack of acceptances.

Comment: That's essentially what I'm trying to do, filter out the crap questions, which (IMO) are always asked by the same kind of user... those who ask a lot of questions and don't accept any answers.

Comment: @Shaggy: Easier to learn what a bad question smells like (then you can avoid them unless you are feeling generous and helpful). Really. Around here we try to judge the content, not the user.